# PL/SQL Add Multiple Columns to Query with Single Function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way to accomplish something like this in PL/SQL...

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, myFunc(a.id) from myTable a;
```

and the result be more than 4 columns?  So basically, is there a way for a function to return or pipe more than one column back?  The number needed is known and set in stone, it's 3.  So this query would return 6 columns.  I know I could call the `myFunc()` 3 separate times but the amount of processing would be tripled.

I've been playing around with pipeline functions but it doesn't appear they can be used to do this.

> Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit
>
> Production PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Thanks!

Comment: If the size of the tuple to be returned by the function is "known and set in stone," then why not write the query to include the three columns?

Comment: @Kirby the columns returned by the function are from other tables.  A join may work but it would be a lengthy and elaborate join that would need to be used in many different queries so I don't want to have to keep re-writing that join.  So then I say, well make a view and have all the queries be based off the view, then I won't have to keep re-writing that join.  That may work, but currently the code is in a function and it is elaborate, I'm not sure if it all can be done in SQL.  Going through it all now.

Answer (score 3):

Here are ways to do it in various Oracle versions.  I use `DBA_OBJECTS` only as a substitute for your real table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_func_rec IS OBJECT
(
  mf_col1 NUMBER,
  mf_col2 NUMBER,
  mf_col3 NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_func_tab IS TABLE OF my_func_rec;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func (id NUMBER)
  RETURN my_func_tab IS
  l_result   my_func_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT my_func_rec (id + 100, id + 101, id + 102)
  BULK   COLLECT INTO l_result
  FROM   DUAL;

  RETURN l_result;
END my_func;
```

#### 12c

In 12c, it's pretty simple using `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT object_id,
       object_type,
       status,
       mf_col1,
       mf_col2,
       mf_col3
FROM   dba_objects o
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT mf_col1,
                           mf_col2,
                           mf_col3
                    FROM   TABLE (my_func (o.object_id)) odet);
```

#### 11g

In 11g, you do not have access to `CROSS APPLY` so you need to select the function results as an object and then `TREAT` it as an object to get access to the individual fields.

```
SELECT object_id,
       object_type,
       status,
       TREAT (val AS my_func_rec).mf_col1,
       TREAT (val AS my_func_rec).mf_col2,
       TREAT (val AS my_func_rec).mf_col3
FROM   (SELECT object_id,
               object_type,
               status,
               (SELECT my_func_rec (mf_col1, mf_col2, mf_col3)
                FROM   TABLE (my_func (o.object_id)) mf)
                 val
        FROM   dba_objects o)
```

NOTE: I created the 11g answer after the 12c answer.  The 11g answer can be further simplified by having `my_func` return a `my_func_rec` instead of a `my_func_tab`.  In this case, it would simplify to:

```
SELECT object_id,
       object_type,
       status,
       TREAT (val AS my_func_rec).mf_col1,
       TREAT (val AS my_func_rec).mf_col2,
       TREAT (val AS my_func_rec).mf_col3
FROM   (SELECT object_id,
               object_type,
               status,
               my_func (o.object_id) val
        FROM   dba_objects o)
```

Comment: You can only keep the full answer part as answer as the earlier section was bit confusing when i started looking at from beginning.

Comment: You are right, @XING.  I've reorganized it for (hopefully) better clarity.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A very simplied illustration. Hope it helps.

```
--The best way here is to make a table type function
--as mentioned below


--Create object type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_DUM
IS
  OBJECT
  (
    COL1 NUMBER,
    COL2 NUMBER,
    COL3 VARCHAR2(100) );
    /

--Create table type    
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TAB_DUM
IS
  TABLE OF OBJ_DUM;
  /


--Create dummy function. This canbe a pipelined function also 
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION SO_DUM
  RETURN TAB_DUM
AS
  lv_tab tab_dum:=tab_dum(NULL,NULL,NULL);
BEGIN
  SELECT obj_dum(level,level+1,'AVRAJIT+'
    ||LEVEL) BULK COLLECT
  INTO lv_tab
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 2;
  RETURN lv_tab;
END;
/


--To check the output
SELECT TAB.*,OBJ.* FROM USER_OBJECTS OBJ,TABLE(SO_DUM) TAB;
```